# Conversational Form with React. How to make multiple choice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chatbot

I am working with React(Next.js). I have a good example `[https://codepen.io/space10/pen/JMXzGX][1]` how to use multiple choise in simple HTML, but how to use it in React?

Here is my code
[image]

Here what I have in browser
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWLjG.png]

Comment: Please, don't post code as image.

Comment: I tried to post in normal way with tags "pre" and "code". But editordidn;t let me post my code, because he has some strange ruels of formatting. That's why after 15 vinutes of tryies, I just put it as a picture.

Comment: Sergey, please check [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I think it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep adding objects into the array - as long as the `name` is the same, it seems to combine it.

Working Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-conversational-form-with-radio

```
    this.formFields = [
      {
        'tag': 'input',
        'type': 'radio',
        'name': 'country',
        'cf-questions': 'What is your country?',
        'cf-label': 'ukraine',
        'value': 'ukraine',
      },
      {
        'tag': 'input',
        'type': 'radio',
        'name': 'country',
        'cf-label': 'india',
        'value': 'india',
      },
      {
        'tag': 'input',
        'type': 'radio',
        'name': 'country',
        'cf-label': 'sri lanka',
        'value': 'sri lanka',
      },
      {
        'tag': 'input',
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'lastname',
        'cf-questions': 'What is your lastname?'
      }
    ];
```

Returns the form result something like this:

```
{ country: ["ukraine"], lastname: 'tasdasd' }
```